# MacOS X Yosemite Apache localhost ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess, osx-yosemite

I'm trying my hand at HTML and PHP. My goal is to create a password protected site that gets gif-images from the server and displays them in a table. Nothing to fancy. For this to work I tried PHP. To test this locally (I don't have a server anyway) I set up my localhost as described here: https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/setup-local-web-server-apache-php-osx-yosemite.html.

Everything worked well, no problems whatsoever.
Then I tried to setup a password protection for my local site.
I created a .htaccess file and saved it in my site-directory with this content:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Then I created a .htpasswd in the same directory and manually inserted a user/password that I generated here: http://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator.

I saved both files and refreshed my page. I was prompted to enter a username and password which I entered. Since then I get a message in my browser that localhost refused the connection "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

Now I can't access localhost anymore. The same error occurs. I tried to restart apache. Then I tried simply restarting my computer. Afterwards I tried to go through the guide again from the beginning. What could be the problem? Is there a way to simply reset my apache to defaults?

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED sounds like a network-level error like the port is not open, not related to the .htpasswd setup. When you restarted Apache, are you certain it successfully started up?  Have a look in the Apache error logs (probably /var/log/apache2 but I'm not sure where they'll be on Mac OS) and see if there are any startup errors listed there.

Comment: Look in the apache2.conf for the `Listen` lines - they should be listening on port 80, probably all interfaces

Comment: Apache seems to be running. I checked in the acitivity monitor and there are two "httpd" processes running, one from the user "root" and one from "_www".

Comment: The listen port is 80.

Comment: I guess I should have checked earlier. But it seems I can access localhost if I use "http://"  instead of "https://". I guess this will work for me, but still, I can't explain why it worked with https before.

Comment: For https, you would need a `Listen 443 https` somewhere too.